# assertion fails when find contours

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting the following error here:

```
error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

This is my code

```
def detectBoxes(img):
    image = np.asarray(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gradient = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV32F)
    kernel = np.ones((15,15),np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(gradient, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    closing = cv2.cvtColor(closing, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im2, cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

I think it's because findContours needs another type of color conversion, but I'm unsure about which one.
Any clues here? Thanks

Comment: Before `cv2.cvtColor()`, try `print image.shape` to check the dimension of numpy matrix you are trying to apply `cv2.cvtColor` upon ?

Comment: @ZdaR the dimension is (3509,2480)

Comment: The given dimension `(3509,2480)` is already in grayscale format, if it had been a 3 channel RGB image then the `image.shape` would have returned: `(3509,2480, 3)`. So you are actually trying to convert an already gray-scale image to gray-scale assuming that it is RGB, just remove the `cvtColor`  thing.

Comment: @ZdaR but when I remove the second cvtColor, I've got the following error: FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only if function cvStartFindContours_Impl

Comment: That is because `cv2.findContours()` is expecting an image without floating values, but your `closing` seems to be of `32-bit floating` type, you can confirm this by `closing.dtype`, if yes then please convert it to `uchar` type using `closing = np.astype(np.uint8)` before passing to findcontours.

Comment: @ZdaR After adding closing.astype(np.uint8) I'm getting the same error

Comment: Have you used `closing = closing.astype(np.uint8)` or `closing.astype(np.uint8)`? You have to use the former one.

Comment: @ZdaR now it works! Thanks a lot man. If you want to post this as an answer I'll mark it as answered

Comment: No worries you can also post the answer. I am glad that I was of help to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ZdaR said in the comments:

> That is because cv2.findContours() is expecting an image without floating values, but your closing seems to be of 32-bit floating type, you can confirm this by closing.dtype, if yes then please convert it to uchar type using closing = np.astype(np.uint8) before passing to findcontours.